# Freebase - MQL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, freebase, mql

the example on the freebase site

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Manual_Javascript_Example

uses http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread

```
<script>                                
function listAlbums(band) {     // Display albums by the specified band.
    var envelope = {                       // The mqlread query envelope
    query : {                          // The MQL query 
        type: "/music/artist",         // Find a band
        name: band,                    // With the specified name
        album: [{                      // We want to know about albums
        name:null,                 // Return album names
        release_date:null,         // And release dates
        sort: "release_date",      // Order by release date
        "release_type!=":"single"  // Don't include singles
        }]
    }
    };

    var output = $("#output");                          // Output goes here
    output.html("<h1>Albums by " + band + "</h1>");     // Display a title

    // Invoke mqlread and call the function below when it is done.
    // Adding callback=? to the URL makes jQuery do JSONP instead of XHR.
    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?callback=?",
           {query: JSON.stringify(envelope)},   // URL parameters
           displayResults);                     // Callback function

    // This function is invoked when we get the result of our MQL query
    function displayResults(response) {  
    if (response.code == "/api/status/ok" &&        
        response.result && response.result.album) { // Check for success...
        var list = $("<ul>");                       // Make <ul> tag.
        output.append(list.hide())                  // Keep it hidden
        var albums = response.result.album;         // Get albums.
        jQuery.each(albums, function() {            // Loop through albums.
        list.append($("<li>").html(this.name)); // Make <li> for each.
        });
        list.show("normal");                        // Reveal the list
    }
    else {                                          // On failure...
        output.append("Unknown band: " + band);     // Display message.
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

that's apparently deprecated; are there any examples of code using the new https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread API? Can't seem to find much online (I'm still learning the ropes).

Answer (score 2):

There have been a couple changes to the new APIs. You can run that same query in Javascript using the new APIs like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var API_KEY = 'YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE';
  var service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread';
  var band = "The Rolling Stones";
  var query = {                         
    type: "/music/artist",        
    name: band,                   
    album: [{                     
    name:null,                
    release_date: null,        
    sort: "release_date",     
    "release_type!=":"single"  
    }]
  };
  var params = {
    'key': API_KEY,
    'query': JSON.stringify(query)
  };
  $.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?', params, function(response) {
    $.each(response.result.album, function(i, album) {
      $('<div>', {text:album['name']}).appendTo(document.body);
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For testing purposes you can run Shawn's example without any API key by just commenting out (or deleting) the 'key':API_KEY line. @Shawn it seems like this would be a useful addition to the documentation in the wiki.